# server choose enabled or not supported protocols:sslv3

Tags: java, https, httpclient

I'm trying to connect to a server use https via httpClient3.5 but without success. The connection fails with a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. When I debug, the value of SSLSocket. getEnabledProtocols() is {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"}, and SSLSocket. getSupportedProtocols() is { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1", "SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3" }, server choose "SSLv3". Shouldn't the server choose one protocol from {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"}? Can anyone explain why server choose "SSLv3"?

But when I use only "TLSv1", that is SSLSocket. getEnabledProtocols()={TLSv1"}, everything works OK.

Here is the exception got on the client side:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose SSLv3, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:445)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:199)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```